# Visual Studio Code - Deletes lines of code upon saving via CTRL+S

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

I've been having an ongoing issue with VSCode that I find very frustrating. I'm coding on GoLang, and whenever I press CTRL+S sometimes it would delete whole lines, or just random digits. I haven't been able to recognize a pattern to it, and it doesn't always happen but it has become an increasingly annoying issue.

Ways I've tried to fix it include:

- reinstalling VSCode
- reinstalling Go
- disabling auto-format on save, as well as every kind of auto format

I also haven't been able to find anyone else with this issue to consult with them. Thank you for reading and please let me know if you could find the source of this problem.

VSCode: v1.69.2
Go version: 1.19

A Screenshot of the issue - before vs after ctrl+s

[before CTRL+S](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gLfkM.png)

[after CTRL+S](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ZAV9.png)

Comment: Have you tried disabling your extensions and trying to reproduce the issue? Maybe also you can list the extensions you have installed in your question so people can try to reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 3):

Uninstalled all unused extensions and haven't encountered the issue since then

Answer (score 0):

**Follow Below Steps :**

Step 01:
I have disabled all extensions and close VS Code

Step 02:
Open VS Code and enable only required extensions.